# jQuery/javascript optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#mySelect").change(function() {

  var myVar = $('#MyDiv');

  for (var i=0;i<this.value;i++)
    {
     myVar.clone().appendTo('#formContainer');
    }
});
```

Any improvements to readability or performance welcome

Comment: This kind of question could be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: isn't it bad practice to put { on it's own line in javascript?

Comment: It is, read: http://javascript.crockford.com/style1.html

Comment: Ugh. Style is a personal thing - it's more important that everyone looking at the file does it the same way than to do it "right".

Comment: @ianbarker That's not something I've ever heard before, and really doesn't make any sense to me. I almost always put the `{` and `}` characters in my code on their own lines; it just makes it that much more readable to me.

Comment: Something to do with the fact that javascript will automatically add `;` where it's needed. I've never seen it cause a problem, but just read about it somewhere

Comment: Doesn't this result in a bunch of DOM elements that all have the same `id` attribute of `MyDiv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Diodeus, you should go with creating html string and then append it in one go. Try this.

```
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  var myVar = $('#MyDiv'),
      html = [],
      count = parseInt(this.value, 10),
      myDivHTML = $('#MyDiv').wrap('<div />').parent().html();
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
     myVar.push(myDivHTML);
  }
  $('#formContainer').append(html.join(''));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

DOM re-writes are the most expensive. Build your HTML up in memory (or as a string) and insert it in one go AFTER the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are (that's how I would do):

```
$("#mySelect").live('change', function() {
    var html = $('<div />').append($('#my-div').clone());
    for (var i = 0; i < this.value; i++) {
        html.append(html.clone());
    }
});
```

If I got right, your trying to nest clone in div on each iteration... that seems strange to me... Also use `live('change', ...);` to bind triggers, in this case your code would work not just for loaded at the beginning HTML, but for loaded via AJAX too.